# Row Number function starting from the max row number of another table in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a query in which I require the row number to start from the max(row_number) of another table. How can I do this considering hive doesn't allow nested queries.

So my query is something like this:

```
Insert Overwrite Table ABC
Select row_number() over (order by Population_Count desc) + select (max(country_id))+1 as country_id,
country_name from ABC_temp;
```

So if the table ABC_temp has the country_id finishing at 26, The ABC table's row_count() should start from 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert Overwrite Table ABC

Select      row_number() over (order by Population_Count desc) 
          + max(country_id) over ()

from        ABC_temp
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
INSERT overwrite TABLE abc
SELECT (temp.m + row_number() over (
                                    ORDER BY population_count DESC)), country_name
FROM abc_temp ,
  (SELECT max(country_id) AS m
   FROM abc_temp) TEMP ;
```

Comment: This worked for me : 
down vote
accept
You may try this :

INSERT overwrite TABLE abc
SELECT (temp.m + row_number() over (
                                    ORDER BY population_count DESC)), country_name
FROM abc_temp JOIN (SELECT max(country_id) AS m
   FROM abc_temp) TEMP ON TRUE